# How do you connect a device pin AIo when there is only AI0+ and AI0-

Tags: analog, pins

I am new to electronics and I faced this problem. I tried to search about it but got lost.

Here is the sensor and the DAQ device

https://docs-emea.rs-online.com/webdocs/13ec/0900766b813ecfc2.pdf

https://sourceforge.isae.fr/attachments/download/1824/IO_myRio_msp.png

Thank you

Comment: Tell us what device that is, where its datasheet is, and the characteristics of the signal.

Comment: Did you mean AIo or AI0 in your title? Please fix it if it's wrong.

Comment: Your "device" is not a sensor. It's a mechanical device known as a potentiometer. It has three terminals. What exactly are you trying to connect and to where, and what's your goal? Surely, your circuit is more than just a potentiometer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The device will measure the voltage between AIx+ and AIx-. If you want to measure a single ended voltage, connect **-** to **GND** and **+** to the signal. Let's suppose you connect the potentiometer between **GND** and the power supply and you want to measure the voltage on the middle pin: Connect the middle pin to AI+, and AI- to GND.